# How to add multiple columns using model.addRow?

Tags: java, model, jtable, jdatechooser

I want to add three variables into three different columns of a row but am running into a problem as I don't know how to add multiple columns at once with model.addRow.

My main problem is that I have to use model.addRow in order to convert my jDateChooser variable into one that can be input into the jTable and see no way of adapting it to my need.

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String theDate = dateFormat.format(jDateChooser1.getDate());
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();

    String Name = jTextField1.getText();

    model.addRow(new Object[]{theDate});
```

'Name' is one of the variables that I want to put into another column, but I see no way of getting it into the table as it is. The code above is under the jButtonActionPerformed event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all the values to the columns in the table. Suppose you have 4 columns and you need to add a row with 3rd value equal to `name` and rest empty.

```
model.addRow(new Object[] {"", "", name, ""});
```

Adding just 1 column does not help